# Conversion of graphics

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

since I am lacking of skills in tikz and others, I am currently doing some graphics in Powerpoint (Word) and trying to include them into LaTeX afterwards. For now, I am copying the graphic into paint, where I save them as .PNG-file. However, I get a pretty bad solution in the .PNG-file itself, in LaTeX it even looks way worse than in the origial. Do you have a better solution for me, so I can enjoy high-res graphics in LaTex?

Best wishes,
Jens

Comment: I suggest you to learn how to draw vector images using Inkscape. Then export it to PDF and include in LaTeX.

Comment: PowerPoint can be used to generate pdf images too. Install some virtual printer drivers such as PDFCreator.

Comment: So you suggest preferring .pdf over .png?

Comment: A vector format such as `.pdf` is always to prefer over a bitmap format as `.png` or `.jpg`

Comment: @Jens, yes. PDF is a vectorial format so you can scale it without loss quality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [`Metafile to EPS converter`](http://wiki.lyx.org/Windows/MetafileToEPSConverter). It's a windows utility which allows you to `paste` some powerpoint figure and converts it to eps. After that you can use any `eps to pdf` converter to get a cropped pdf file which can be easily included in your document with `\includegraphics`. With `epstopdf` package in document preamble you get an `on-the-fly` conversion from eps to pdf.

Comment: That's an awesome and even simple solution that offers best quality. In my source, the ways to achieve a converted files are basically way more complicated and/or cost more time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did some research due to the helpful comments.

This link actually grants a nice overview on how to use/transfer Powerpoint-pictures in an adequate format for LaTeX:

https://www.cs.bu.edu/~reyzin/pictips.html