# Is there any tool that convert a Pie Chart (and others) from MS Excel to LaTex Code?

Tags: conversion

I am looking for a tool (if it exist) that given a chart from MS Excel return the LaTeX code to insert in a document.

Comment: do you need to _convert_ it? You can just use `\includegraphics` to include the excel generated image.

Comment: [MetaFile to eps converter](http://wiki.lyx.org/Windows/MetafileToEPSConverter) worked for me with powerpoint graphics so I think it can also work with excel pie charts. Already suggested at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186213/1952

Comment: If you _really, really, really_ want piecharts, why not generate them in LaTeX. Convert your *xc*l spreadsheet to csv format and then use a package such as `datatool` (`datapie`) to generate the pie chart.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this workflow in the past for moving large numbers of graphs from Excel to a Latex document:

From Excel, print the chart to an .eps file format using a generic postscript printer device. In Latex, embed the .eps file.

Here's an online resource that has templates to get started: http://embedded.eecs.berkeley.edu/concurrency/latex/latexWithEPS.html

Comment: In newer versions of ms office pdf export is available.